# How to manually trigger an downarrow keyboard event in Monaco Editor?

Tags: selenium, testing, monaco-editor

I'm in charge of testing (with selenium) a Monaco editor field in our webapp.
I know how to trigger the completions dropdown with:

```
editor.trigger('', 'editor.action.triggerSuggest')
```

But the completion list is big and I'd like to navigate in this list by using the downarrow key.
How can I fire this event? I tried with no luck:

```
editor.trigger('', 'type', monaco.KeyCode.DownArrow)
```

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: for Selenium it is: element.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);

Comment: @pcalkins Unfortunately, Monaco editor doesn't response to any standard selenium way to interact with DOM that's why you have to use their API.

Answer (score 0):

As @alexdima answered in https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1872

```
editor.trigger('', 'selectNextSuggestion')
```

it totally works!

Just a side note, you can also fire selenium keyboard events on the embedded textarea of your Monaco element:

```
$(monaco_element).find("textarea").get(0).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
```