# where is the monaco-editor trigger function documentation?

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor, react-monaco-editor

in Monaco-editor in react, I want to manually trigger some keyboard commands and I can't find any suitable documentation for it. for example when you want to enter backspace like this:

`editor.trigger('keyboard', 'deleteLeft', null)`

or if you want to type something:

`editor.trigger('keyboard', 'type', {text: 'hi'})`

where are the other commands like 'deleteLeft' or 'type'?

I found some commands in stackoverflow or GitHub issues but it's insufficient.
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66933107/monaco-editor-how-to-trigger-backspace)- [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60648444/how-to-manually-trigger-an-downarrow-keyboard-event-in-monaco-editor) - [3](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1872)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of all supported actions using this code:

```js
        editor.getSupportedActions().forEach((value: Monaco.IEditorAction) => {
            console.log(value);
        });
```

This helped me to find actions/commands for specific tasks.